# Is it possible for me to get rid of the end of line character after an input?

Tags: c++

```
char choice;
float inputa, inputb;
cin >> inputa >> choice >> inputb;

while(inputa != 0 && choice != '0' && inputb != 0)
{
    cout << " = " << calculation(inputa,choice,inputb) << endl << endl;
    cin >> inputa >> choice >> inputb;
}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

This is what the screen looks like:

```
5 + 4
 = 9
```

The user gives their input and presses enter, so that's what takes them to the next line I guess, but is there a way for it to show:

```
5 + 4 = 9
```

After the result is shown, it would use the `endl` to go to the next line and the user can input their problem again.

I'm a complete beginner so sorry if the question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Don't add the [c] tag to a c++ question.

Comment: @rullof The calculation function doesn't seem to apply to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use do it since `cin` prints every character after you hit it. You will have to define your own input function.

For exemple you can use `getch` in the `conio.h` (**This is not an efficient solution since getch accept only one character. You will have to fin another way. The importent here is to get the idea**).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void input(float *a, char *c, float *b)
{
    char in;
    do {
        in = getch();
        cout << in;
    } while (in == ' ');
    *a = in - '0';
    do {
        in = getch();
        cout << in;
    } while (in == ' ');
    *c = in;
    do {
        in = getch();
        cout << in;
    } while (in == ' ');
    *b = in - '0';
}

int main()
{
    char choice;
    float inputa, inputb;
    cout << "Expression: ";
    input(&inputa, &choice, &inputb);
    cout << " = " << inputa+inputb << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Shahzad this is not the best way to do it since with getch you can only get one digit? Try to find some other more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways to achieve what you are looking for.

First - you could delete last character from terminal before cout, so the endl is canceled.

Second - you could turn off echo on your terminal, switch off input buffering and handle whole input echoing yourself.

Unfortunately, both methods are inaccessible from pure C++. You have to use some terminal API depending on your platform (conio.h on Windows and termios.h on Linux). While the first approach is much easier to code I am not sure if it's possible on all platforms. Universal solution isn't possible at all.

I know it might sound terrifying for a beginner so you might be satisfied with much easier solution which might still suit your needs. You can find whatever command clear the whole terminal on your platform (clear on Linux, and cls on Windows), call it via system function from cstdlib and print whole equation.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   float a,b; char choice;
   cin>>a>>choice>>b;
   system("clear"); //on Windows "cls"
   cout<<a<<choice<<b<<"="<<calculation(a,choice,b)<<"\n";
   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @pkuik In windows you may use `system(cls);` but it is not a good idea to clear the screen since you may loose something importent.

Comment: @rullof Beginners often look for simple solutions. I presented a specific way to realise given task - the calculator, hence I found clearing the screen non-intrusive.
Thanks, for pointing proper Windows command.